# Is it worth killing the Training Robot?

Tags: the-gold-factory

On the training center where you buy and upgrade your spell you can spend 20 gold bars in a battle to "test your skill" with a Training Robot.

It does reward something killing it?

Comment: the damage of your weapon increases - barely perceptible at the start, though

Comment: @kleopatra Are you sure about it? Well, the damage of the weapon can be seen during battles, I will test it on the evening and I tell you the conclusions.

Comment: yeah, increased mine steadily :-) Though only started to notice when I had about 35 ir so, and the increase is low, something like 1 or 2 per victory. It's like trading health potions for damage (and time to battle) as the robot increases its max health and damage along with your own.

Comment: @kleopatra you're right!I checked. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Winning in a training battle increases the damage of your attacks. It's barely noticeable at the beginning, started to see a change - about 1 point per victory - around the middle of the thirties.

Comment: And it also gives you gold when you win (increasingly?)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you get as much gold as the robot has hp every time you win. I have a diamond sword with 405 damage, and gain about 470 gold per round. Coincidentally, my robot has that amount of hp... ;)