# What is the maximum enchanting level?

Tags: the-gold-factory

What is the maximum enchantment level for **Attack** and **Life** on the sword? I'm on level 5 of both and every time it costs more and more!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Life** (and *Defense*) enchantment has a hard cap of *Level 10*.

The **Attack** enchantment is *unlimited*.

Comment: Actually the defense enchantment is "hidden and deprecated" enchantment (as you can see at the source code)

Comment: @gamehelp16 It was still available in some of the early popular builds, hence why I kept the information around.

Comment: Note that [killing the training robot](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/146783/88) is a much cheaper way to increase your attack